# testing a website in windows phone 7 simulator

Tags: windows-phone-7

I'm trying to test a mobile website I'm building using Windows Phone 7, but I can't figure out how to do it. It seems that the SDK wants me to build an application first in order to use the emulator, but I'm not building an app, I simply want to test compatibility of my mobile site with windows phones. How do I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you install the free Windows Phone SDK you can run an emulator in standalone mode (i.e. without Visual Studio running).

Search for "Windows Phone Emulator" from the Start menu and just launch that directly.

Once in the emulator about the only thing you can do is launch IE Mobile.

(To enter URLs and other text using your real computer keyboard instead of the onscreen keyboard tap your "Pause/Break" to toggle keyboard mode)

Comment: This worked, but the emulator apparently doesn't support my graphics card(?) Wow. I'm running windows 7 from a mac. Maybe that's an issue.

Comment: I would rather check if CPU supports virtualization

Comment: Both CPU and GPU could be an issue. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff626524(v=vs.92).aspx

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to run emulator without building an app 
try C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Phone\v7.0\Tools\XDE Launcher\XdeLauncher.exe

If now start visual studio and make an app f.e. Silverlight for Windows 7. Emulator will be loaded with debbuger attached. If you stop the app in VS, emulator should be still there. It has preinstalled IE which you can use to test.

Mind that it's better to test your web app on a real device.

Comment: If it's a HTML5 site, I would recommend using the 7.1 tools, rather than the 7.0 ones.